# center the modal image: which <div> to style?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have created a modal image inside of a Bootstrap 4 carousel with JQuery. Problem is when I open it, it is not centered in the screen. Which div between the parents is to style and how? Also, to make it proportional (responsive) in case of smaller screens, how to style the size of the image?

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">      
      <img class="pop d-block" src="images/getonboard.png" alt="First slide">
    </div>
  <div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="javascript:void(0) role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="javascript:void(0) role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>


<!-- Modal Images Link -->


<!-- Geton Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
   labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div style="width: 800px; height: 500px;" class="modal-content">              
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria- 
          hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span> 
         </button>
        <img src="images/getonboard.png" class="imagepreview" style="width: 
         100%;" >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



$(function() {
    $('.pop').on('click', function() {
      $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
      $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
    });   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hardcoded styling onto your class `modal-content`. Try removing the style and it should work as intended.

`<div style="width: 800px; height: 500px;" class="modal-content">`.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/2ofkxa8r/

Comment: It still displays the image in a very small box...do you think it could have inherited some styling?

Comment: Are you talking about the original image being clicked, or inside of the modal? You can try adding width: 100% instead. https://jsfiddle.net/2ofkxa8r/2/

Comment: the clicked one...I think it inherits some style from Bootstrap not allowing of being larger...http://it.tinypic.com/r/2el5hf5/9

Comment: @Enrico please let me know if this works for you: https://jsfiddle.net/2ofkxa8r/12/

Answer (score 2):

You've added inline styles to modal-content. So thats why it's not centered.

```
<div style="width: 800px; height: 500px;" class="modal-content">
```

Remove them and use media queries instead.

The "img-fluid" class makes images get the full width of parent element.

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/26/16/06/architecture-2175925_960_720.jpg" class="imagepreview" >
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">      
      <img class="pop d-block" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/26/16/06/architecture-2175925_960_720.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
  <div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>


<!-- Modal Images Link -->


<!-- Geton Modal -->
<div class="modal fade show" style="display: block" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
   labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">              
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria- 
          hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span> 
         </button>
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/26/16/06/architecture-2175925_960_720.jpg" class="imagepreview" >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It still displays the image in a very small box...do you think it could have inheriterd some styling?